# DataTable problema de ordenação no padrão brasileiro de numerais

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-datatables, datatable

estou com um probleminha, aposto que muitos também já passaram por essa situação. Sabemos que existem vários padrões de formatos em diferentes países, eu estou usando um plugin front-end bastante conhecido ao se tratar de tabelas, que é o datatable, e ele possui diversos recursos, e um deles é a ordenação. O padrão de  numerais que a datatable utiliza entende que casas de mil se separa por vírgula e casas decimais por ponto (1,000.0), já o padrão brasileiro é ao contrário (1.000,0). Então o problema é o seguinte, ao inserir essas informações no padrão brasileiro, na hora de ordenar, ela ordena errado por entende que casas de mil são decimais e vice e versa.

Segue a imagem da ordenação incorreta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem ele está ordenando o peso de maneira crescente, e está entendendo que 23.479,5 é menor que 825,5 devido ao posicionamento da pontuação

Alguém sabe me dizer se existe algum método que eu possa sobrescrever o plugin do datatable para adaptar da maneira correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa levar em conta a cultura que esta sendo usada quando for ordenar qualquer coisa. No caso do DataTables aqui estão as instruções para você ordenar levando em conta a cultura utilizada.

[https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/comma-decimal.html`](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/comma-decimal.html)

Comment: Eu tinha resolvido essa questão de outra maneira, mas essa é mais eficaz, obrigado era isso mesmo que estava procurando!